# property or method is not defined in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am creating a web app with Django and using Vue.js in a template file.
When I tried to display icons according to the prepared data, I got the following error.

```
vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Property or method "eval" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. 

vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <star-icon> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
(found in <Root>)
```

I seem to set the properties "eval" via props and put the custom elements in place.

**html**

```
<div id="stars" data-eval="{{ evaluation }}"> <!-- {{ evaluation }} is Number -->
    <ul style="list-style: none;">
        <li class="d-inline-block">
            <star-icon :eval="eval" data-id="1"></star-icon>
            <star-icon :eval="eval" data-id="2"></star-icon>
            <star-icon :eval="eval" data-id="3"></star-icon>
            <star-icon :eval="eval" data-id="4"></star-icon>
            <star-icon :eval="eval" data-id="5"></star-icon>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
var starIcon = {
    props: ["eval"],
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    data: function () {
        return {
            right: false,
            star_id: 0,
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        var elm = this.$el;
        var id = elm.getAttribute('data-id');
        this.star_id = Number(id);
    },
    template: '<i :class="star"></i>',
    computed: {
        star: function () {
            if (this.star_id <= this.eval) {
                this.right = true;
            } else {
                this.right = false;
            };
            return {
                fas: this.right,
                far: !this.right,
                'fa-star': true,
                'fa-yellow': true,
                'fa-2x': true
            };
        }
    },
}

new Vue({
    el: '#stars',
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    components: {
        'star-icon': starIcon,
    },
    data: {
        eval: 3,
    },
    beforeMount: function () {
        var elm = this.$el;
        var evaluation = elm.getAttribute('data-eval');
        this.eval = Number(evaluation);
        console.log(this.eval);
    },
})
```

The last line, console.log(this.eval);, returned a valid number, so this part seems to work.

How can I resolve the above error?

Thank you.

Comment: instead of `<star-icon>` try `<starIcon>` since thats how you defined it. 

What are wanting `eval` to be? Your `console.log(this.eval)` is showing you the value your setting in the data object (3). You should be able to delete that data object from the vue instance and either add it back to the component definition or not use it at all and hardcode it in the template `eval="3"`  i also recommend adding [vue dev tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en) if you're using Chrome - its a quality tool when your working with Vue

Comment: thank you for replying.Changing <star-icon> to <starIcon> didn't work either.The {{ evaluation }} in the template is the data received from the backend (Django) and its value is 2. data: {eval: 3} in the Vue instance is set to the default value and is overwritten with 'this.eval = Number(evaluation)'. As a result, console.log(this.eval) shows 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the cause, but when I changed the script import order, the display worked fine. But there are still errors...